# How to upload large size( more than 100 MB) folder to two different S3 bucket of AWS without interruption in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am following the below step to do the same

1) First I transfer the zip file to EC2 which contain a html file and a folder (containing js and css files)

2) Then I unzipped it into a folder named timestamp (14585857) in EC2 
(that timestamp folder is kept under webroot/temp/ )

3) Then I moved unzipped folder using uploadDirectory function, zip file using putObject function and html file using putObject function to first S3 bucket (region of first S3 bucket is ap-southeast-1)

4) After successfully transfer to first S3 bucket then I moved same unzipped folder, zip file and html file to second S3 bucket (region of second S3 bucket is eu-west-1)

Here, problem is when I upload small sized file (about 40 to 80 MB) then it works perfectly fine But when I try to upload file which is above 100 MB in size then sometimes it works and sometimes get interrupted

Any suggestion, how I can upload large size file or find any improvement in my process.

Comment: Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: I believe the issue may be due to your max execution time, which is set to 30 seconds by default. You could change it just for your script using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes` or similar.

Comment: Are you uploading the file via php + apache? I would recommend that you upload the file as a php script in the background so that you can tune the upload process for time and memory restrictions.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, @Nicolas I have updated both the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size but still get same error,

Comment: @JamesWalker I have set max_execution_time but still not working.
any other suggestion